# Background Image playthrough - Causing page to move back to top

Tags: jquery, html, css

On [a website I have made](http://www.jesmonddenehouse.co.uk)

I have a `<header>` and a `<section>` in my HTML document.

The header has a fading background image in it, What is happening is when the new image is loading if you are further down the page i.e in the section part, The site is jumping straight back to the top .

Is there any way to fix this?

I have tried a few CSS fixes and the likes but just had no luck.

jQuery :

```
    var counter = 0;

// Playthrough Background Images
    var imgArray = ['http://www.jesmonddenehouse.co.uk/addons/shared_addons/themes/jesmonddene/img/home/banner1.jpg',
        'http://www.jesmonddenehouse.co.uk/addons/shared_addons/themes/jesmonddene/img//home/banner2.jpg',
        'http://www.jesmonddenehouse.co.uk/addons/shared_addons/themes/jesmonddene/img//home/banner3.jpg',
        'http://www.jesmonddenehouse.co.uk/addons/shared_addons/themes/jesmonddene/img/home/banner4.jpg'
    ]
    var nextBG = "url(" + imgArray[counter] + ")";

    $('.home-page').css("background-image", nextBG);

    setInterval(function(){
        counter++;
        nextBG = "url(" + imgArray[counter % imgArray.length] + ")";
        $('.home-page').fadeOut('fast', function() {
            $(this).css("background-image", nextBG).fadeIn('fast'); })
    }, 4000); // 4 second interval
```

CSS

```
#header {
    overflow:hidden;
    height:auto;
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height:100%;
    position: relative;
}
.no-touch #header {
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

Thanks

**edit** I would add a jsFiddle, But the site is built in PyroCMS and would take a while to piece together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use zindex css property as below

```
.no-touch #header {
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    zindex:1000; or zindex:-1000;
}
```

whichever suits better

Comment: Hi, I've moved the #header to a seperate DIV and that seems to have fixed the issue.